# Change the html lang attribute in nextJS dynamically from separate lang page

Tags: next.js13

I have a nextJS project that is structured such that the lang only affects the blog section of the project. I am having a problem changing the lang attribute in `layout.tsx` appropiately according to the lang.

The directory structure is something like this :

```
src
   [lang]/blog/page.tsx
   home/page.tsx
   layout.tsx
```

here is the code of the `layout.tsx`

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`overflow-x-hidden`}>
            {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

in case, the blog page, has a `fr` lang. I would need the lang value in layout.tsx to be `fr` instead of `en`. How can I achieve this?

NB: the layout.tsx is a **server** component, hence rendered in serverside, and I would love to keep it that way.
I am using `nextJS 13`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution to my problem, using `useEffect()` to set the appropiate `lang`

In the `[lang]blog` directory, I created a file `sections.tsx`, separate from `page.tsx`, reason being, I would need page.tsx to be strictly a server component, and here is where I would fetch my blog data. the `sections.tsx` would contain all the section components of the blog page, and could be a client component since we are using `useEffect` here, specified with "use client"

so the result would be something like this :

`[lang]/blog/page.tsx`

```
...
...
const Blog = async(props: Props) => {
  const lang = props.params.lang;
  const articles = await fetchArticles(lang)

  return (
    <main>
        <Sections
          articles={articles}
          lang={lang}
        />
    </main>
  );
};
```

`[lang]/blog/sections.tsx`

```
"use client"

...
...
const Sections:React.FC<sectionProps> = ({
    articles,lang
    }) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        if(lang){
            document.documentElement.setAttribute("lang", lang); //set the lang here
        }
      }, [lang])

    return(
        <>
          <SectionOne/> //sections here
          .... 
        </>
    )
}
```

I hope this can help someone else in the same situation.